# Why is the ceiling cracking?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

The house was built less than 10 years ago and the ceiling is already showing cracks. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: What’s above it? My gut feel is that it’s caused by moisture.

Comment: I removed the cost question because that's explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You'll have to get estimates from local contractors to find out what it costs. Even if I were a contractor, I couldn't give you a good estimate because I wouldn't know what raw materials and labor would cost for your area, nor exactly how much work needs to be done based on a single picture.

Comment: *The house was built less than 10 years ago...* Any chance it came with a 10 year warranty?

Answer (score 30):

I think you have a leak. There appears to be water damage (the darker areas) around it; that would cause a seam to split or drywall tape to delaminate.

Cost is off-topic on this site. You need to get multiple quotes for repairs, but more important than the drywall is the leak. That needs found and corrected.

Comment: My eyes see *another* dark water spot on the right of the photo.

Answer (score 19):

I agree with the leak assessment, but here's some tips on what's going on

The spot in your picture is where the joints of two sheets of drywall were taped (which is the technical term) together with drywall mud. There's a crease that runs down the middle of the drywall tape. The water has softened the mud and soaked into the tape. Gravity has done the rest.

The catch you need to look out for is that your leak has found the lowest point to settle in. **The leak may not be directly above this spot.** You'll need to look in the vicinity for any other sources of water.

Repairing this is going to be a mess as well. You have spackled ceilings. Once the leak is fixed, patching won't work very well. This spot will stick out like a sore thumb if you do. I would highly recommend you scrape the ceiling down (wet it first so it scrapes easily). Then I would repair the drywall joint and then simply paint it. Makes any future repairs much easier.

Comment: what about the actual (textured) ceiling itself that is flaking and peeling? Is that drywall mud or is it just a layer of paint? thanks

Comment: It's a type of drywall mud. You'll have to put new mud up to patch it, which will not match the color of the existing texture

Comment: "...future repairs...:  You are such an optimist!  8)

Comment: +1 for the leak may not be above this spot. In fact is it my imagination or is there another wet spot (or at least a former wet spot) in the photo, on the far right, just down from the top corner of the picure?

Comment: @Machavity Since the construction is within the last 10 years (in the US), the drywall mud shouldn't contain any asbestos right?

Comment: @dataengineer22 Yes. Popcorn ceilings are the more troublesome ones, as popcorn through about 1990 could contain it. You have a simple textured ceiling, so it's highly likely to just be texturing mud.